# How can I stop Google reviewers from deleting the account I have provided for testing?

Tags: android, mobile, review

Almost every time our app is sent for review (Open Testing and Production reviews) the account which I have provided for testing purposes is deleted. I have seen in the pre-launch report screenshots that they take all the steps to delete an account. I have always assumed this process is just an automated monkey-testing, but I cannot be sure. But it feels weird that Google would delete the account they were given, on purpose?

It is very annoying, as I have to setup a new account every time, and add our connected appliances to it.

We cannot be the only ones with this issue. So how does others handle it?

I have tried informing the reviwers in the text-box connected to the login credentials that they should not delete the account, but that does not work.

Previously we also made the account impossible to delete from a backend service, but then we were not sure if this is legally compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your last solution, the user click on the app button "Delete all my data", but obviously on the back end nothing happens and the action is "filtered". Never had a complain about this